# what is the youngest this person can be?

Tags: word-problem

Martha said: “I have been alive for all or part of five decades.” Rounded to the nearest year, what is the youngest she could be?

How can this be solved?

Comment: Hint: the answer will be different depending on what year it is now.

Comment: Hint: if she is as young as possible, she should be born toward the end of a decade, say December 31, 1979 (which would make her alive during the 70s). Then she's also been alive for at least part of the 80's, 90's, 00's, and 10's. Again, to make her as young as possible she should be making this statement toward the beginning of the decade, say January 1st, 2010. How old would that make her at the time of the statement, rounded to the nearest year? Note: the answer is different if we assume she is making the statement *today*, August 22, 2019.

Comment: Simple deduction.  The first and last years can be partial decades, leaving 3 full decades, making a minimum of 30 years (plus fractional parts which could be rounded off).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is 30.

If someone was born December 30, 1979 and passed Jan 2nd, 2010 then they will have lived 30 years and in part of 5 decades (with e.g., the 70s beginning in Jan 1st 1970 and ending Dec 31st, 1979).